# How to sum the same field in SQL without selecting the field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field named kcal (int) and I want to sum it's values for different conditions. If i could select the kcal fields first, it should look like this, but I just want the value of the sum, where the columns meet some conditions.

```
SELECT kcal AS k1, kcal AS k2, kcal AS k3, (k1 + k2 + k3) FROM table WHERE ...
```

EDIT :I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu] (
[id_product]       INT        NOT NULL,
[product_name]  NCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
[description]       TEXT      NULL,
[price]             INT       NOT NULL,
[kcal]              INT       NOT NULL,
[dish]              INT       NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id_product] ASC)
```

);

And i want to display all the combinations possible of 3 product_name (each one with a different dish value(which can be 1, 2 or 3)), the total_kcal of each 3 combinations, the total price of each 3 combinations, with the condition that the sum of price <50 and the sum of kcal < 2000. For that, i wrote this:

```
SELECT (SELECT product_name FROM Menu WHERE dish = 1) AS Dish1, (SELECT product_name FROM Menu WHERE dish = 2) AS Dish2, (SELECT product_name FROM Menu WHERE dish = 3) AS Dish3, SUM(kcal) AS Total_Kcal , SUM(price) as Total_Price FROM Menu WHERE dish IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY dish HAVING SUM(pret) < 50 AND SUM(kcal) < 2000
```

It works just fine, with the problem that the sums are not corresponding.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output

Comment: `SELECT kcal AS k1, kcal AS k2, kcal AS k3, (kcal * 3) ..` doesn't make sense, but would do the same as your invalid query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I know it does not, but i hoped that if i write it like this you will get what i actually need to do. If there was a table with fields Value1 and Value 2 SELECT Value1, Value2, (Value1 + Value2) FROM table; would work

Comment: This is just a bad example because it doesn't answer the question: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The requirement doesn't make much sense. why output the same column  as three separate columns and also, sum it three times?

Comment: Do you want the sum for various mathematical conditions/combinations of other columns?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i explained what i actually want to do

Comment: @Bohemian I edited the question so it makes sense

Comment: This is sql-server right? It's surely not mysql.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this sounds like a CROSS JOIN with a plethora of WHERE conditions to me:

```
SELECT 
  m1.product_name
 ,m2.product_name
 ,m3.product_name
 ,(m1.kcal + m2.kcal + m3.kcal) AS CombinedKcal
 ,(m1.price + m2.price + m3.price) AS CombinedPrice
FROM 
  Menu AS m1
 ,Menu AS m2
 ,Menu AS m3
WHERE
  -- Ensure combinations include each dish only once.
  (m1.id_product <> m2.id_product AND m2.id_product <> m3.id_product AND m3.id_product <> m1.id_product)
AND 
  -- Ensure combinations include a dish 1, a dish 2 and a dish 3
  (m1.dish = 1 AND m2.dish = 2 AND m3.dish = 3)
AND
  -- Ensure Combined Calories is less than 2000
 (m1.kcal + m2.kcal + m3.kcal) < 2000
AND
  -- Ensure Combined Price is less than 50
 (m1.price + m2.price + m3.price) < 50
```

Comment: You are the real MVP. Thank you so much. Had a lot of trouble with this.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, pleased it helped. If there is a better way, I'd be keen to see it because I know cross joins are notoriously inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Either repeat the expressions with the base column names or use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*, (k1 + k2 + k3) 
FROM (SELECT kcal AS k1, kcal AS k2, kcal AS k3
      FROM table
      WHERE ...
     ) t;
```

Why can't you repeat column aliases without a subquery?  Simple.  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.  Hence, the last expression could be the first one executed . . . and `k1` would not be known.

I should also note that using a subquery like this incurs additional overhead because MySQL materializes the subquery.  You should use `(kcal + kcal + kcal)` without a subquery for better performance.

Comment: Can you, please, revisit my question ? I edited it so it matches my needs, and thank you for the answer.